# Jquery Validate com Jquery-Price-Format

Tags: javascript, html5, jquery-validate

Como deixar o campo obrigatório quando o valor for igual 0,00 usando jquery validate ?

Segue exemplo em imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como pode ver a imagem acima, a pessoa não digitou o valor, quando clicar o botão aceitar, o jquery validate funciona normalmente a imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora o problema é quando digitar valor 0,00. Segue a imagem :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como pode ver a imagem acima, o valor não pode ficar com 0,00, deve ser pelo menos 0,01.

Segue o código abaixo:

**Html**:

```
<form id="myform">
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="@Model.Valor" id="valor" name="valor" placeholder="Digite o seu valor">
</form>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$('#valor').priceFormat({
    prefix: 'R$ ',
    centsSeparator: ',',
    thousandsSeparator: '.'
});
```

**Jquery Validate**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#myform").validate({
            ignore: ":hidden",
            rules: {
                valor: { required: true }
            },
            messages: {
                valor: "<span style=\"color: #a94442;\">Campo Valor é obrigatório *</span>"
            },
            highlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            },
            unhighlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) { etc ....}
```

Eu uso [Jquery-Price-Format](http://flaviosilveira.com/Jquery-Price-Format/). Quando digitar valor 0,00, jquery deve mostrar aviso. Quando for 0,01 tirar o aviso do jquery validate. Ou seja, se for igual 0,00, mostrar aviso vermelho. Alguma solução ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deverá criar um `custom` `validation` para esse determinado tipo e remover o `prefix` para que fique somente o valor pra teste, exemplo:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("valuethanmorezero", function(value, element) {
      var valor = value.replace(".",",").replace(",",".");
      return this.optional(element) || (parseFloat(valor) >= 0.01);
}, "Valor tem que maior que 0,01");
```

Agora pode passar na validação igual exemplo completo:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#valor').priceFormat({
    prefix: '',
    centsSeparator: ',',
    thousandsSeparator: '.'
  });
  
  jQuery.validator.addMethod("valuethanmorezero", function(value, element) {
      var valor = value.replace(".",",").replace(",",".");
      return this.optional(element) || (parseFloat(valor) >= 0.01);
  }, "Valor tem que maior que 0,01");
  
  $("#myform").validate({
    ignore: ":hidden",
    rules: {
      valor: {
        required: true,
        valuethanmorezero: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      valor: { 
       required: "<span style=\"color: #a94442;\">Campo Valor é obrigatório *</span>",
        valuethanmorezero:"<span style=\"color: #a94442;\">Valor tem que maior que 0,01*</span>"
      }
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
      $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
      $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {}
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-price-format/2.1/jquery.priceformat.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="0" id="valor" name="valor" placeholder="Digite o seu valor">
  <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

***Referencias***

- [jQuery.validator.addMethod()](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/)
- [jQuery Validate Plugin - How to create a simple custom rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241145/jquery-validate-plugin-how-to-create-a-simple-custom-rule)

Comment: Funcionou aqui. Era só remover prefix como voce falou. Tnks

Answer (score -2):

Insere isto no option do `priceFormat`:

```
clearOnEmpty: true
```